# how to get values of an array that is inside an object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, return

i've got an object that contains two elements, the first is a string, the second one is an array, i need to return only the array.

here is the object :

```
{
"return_code": 0,
"response": [
{
  "tid": "30",
  "categorie": "Fish"
},
{
  "tid": "31",
  "categorie": "Birds"
}
]
}
```

I want to return the "response". Any help please ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is JavaScript, no?

Comment: @IanMcLaird Good question!

Comment: Could be Python. Somewhat oddly, OP thought it not relevant.

Comment: non in PHP please (for drupal)

Comment: The result you see in my question is a GET query from database

Comment: Do you mean that this is the data that the database gave you back in response to your GET?  What kind of database?  MongoDB, perhaps?  What was the query you ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic idea based on new comments:

1. Decode the JSON string you're getting using `json_decode` in PHP. This will give you a PHP object.
2. Create an empty list to contain the elements you want in the result.
3. For each element in the `response` property of the decoded JSON object, add `response.categorie` to your list container.
4. Return the now full list

Comment: Hi Patrick and thank you for you quick response. Actually i need to get this : {"fish","Birds"..ect}

Comment: @Mitch Updated based on your comments here and on the question.

Comment: Great job Patrick i totally forgot to decode Thank you very much

Comment: @Mitch Glad to help. You might consider selecting an answer to help others with the same question later on.

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like JSON, so I will propose a solution in jq ("Json Query") - a language that is readily available on most modern computing platforms -- see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

The originally posted task was to find the array.  In jq, this can be accomplished using the program: .response

Subsequently, the task was revised to extracting the "categorie" values.
This can be accomplished using the program: .response[] | .categorie

Here is an example, assuming your input is in a file named "input.json":

```
$ jq '.response[] | .categorie' input.json
"Fish"
"Birds"
```

Or, if you want to gather these values as a JSON array:

```
$ jq - '[.response[] | .categorie]' input.json
["Fish","Birds"]
```